If $R$ is ufd, then is it true that $R[x]/(x^2+1)$ is ufd?
If $R$ is ufd, then is it true that  $R[x]/(x^2+1)$  is ufd ?
If $R$ is PID, then is it true that  $R[x]/(x^2+1)$  is PID ?
If $R$ is ED, then is it true that  $R[x]/(x^2+1)$  is ED ?
I had this question while seeing the proof of gaussian integers being euclidean domain. But that proof involves taking norm as $a^2+b^2$ and then while calculating the remainde, we do use the fact that the ring is integers. But can it be somehow  generalised?

If $R = \Bbb{C}$, you'll have some problems...

You won't even get,an integral domain all the time.

You should make sure at least that $(X^2 + 1) \subseteq R[X]$ is a prime ideal to have a chance. For example for $R = \mathbb{Z}[i]$ all three do not work.

What's the meaning of ufd, PID and ED?

No. The ring $R = \mathbf Z[\sqrt{3}]$ is a Euclidean domain, and hence a PID and UFD. Then
$$
R[x]/(x^2+1) = R[i] = \mathbf Z[\sqrt{3},i]
$$
and this ring is not integrally closed since $(1+\sqrt{-3})/2$ is in the fraction field of $R$ and is integral over $\mathbf Z$ and thus $R$ but is not in $R$. Thus $R$ is not a UFD or PID or Euclidean domain since they are integrally closed.
